# Add worksheets for every day of the month looping in ascending order

Tags: excel, vba

My loop works, but it's putting them in reverse order.  I realize it's doing exactly what I have below, but I'm not good enough with the syntax yet.I can't figure out how to reverse it.

Current worksheet order is descending: 3.31, 3.30, 3.29, etc...

I need ascending order: 3.21, 3.22, 3.23, 3.24, etc...

days = numerical value days of each month
mon = numerical value of month

Suggestions?

```
For i = 1 To Val(days)
    Sheets(1).Copy after:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = mon & "." & (i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will place the sheets in the correct order at the end of your workbook:

```
For i = 1 To Val(days)
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = mon & "." & (i)
Next i
```

This will place them correctly after sheet1:

```
Set wsTemp = Sheets(1)
For i = 1 To Val(days)
    Set wsTemp = Sheets(1).Copy(After:=wsTemp)
    wsTemp.Name = mon & "." & (i)
Next i
```